# FileProvider.getUriForFile context throwing NullPointer exeption

Tags: java, android, android-fileprovider

I am getting the following error from `FileProvider.getUriForFile`

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResource()' on a null object reference

However, when I display `context.toString()` I get this which (I think) proves that the object is not null:

> uk.co.letsdelight.letsdelight.MainActivity@8eec139

The code writes `Completed download of update file` to logcat but doesn't write `URI successfully set` on an API 24 device.  It works on API 23.  Here is the important part of the code.  The `Update` class is invoked from `MainActivity` with `new Update(status, message).check(this);`

```
public class Update extends Activity {

    private File outputFile;
    private TextView status;
    private TextView message;
    private String TAG = "LETSDELIGHT";

    public Update(TextView status){
        this.status = status;
    }
    public Update(TextView status, TextView message){
        this.status  = status;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void check(final Context c) {
        status.setText("Checking for updates");

        // Check for updates and give user option to update

            // UPDATE button pressed
            UpdateApp updateApp = new UpdateApp();
            updateApp.setContext(c);
            updateApp.execute(c.getString(R.string.apk_uri));
            status.setText("Downloading update");
    }

    public class UpdateApp extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {
        private Context context;
        private Throwable thrown = null;
        private String statusMessage;
        public void setContext(Context contextf){
            context = contextf;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(arg0[0]);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.connect();

                Log.i(TAG,"Starting download of update file");
                statusMessage = "Starting download of update file";

                File file = context.getCacheDir();
                file.mkdirs();
                outputFile = new File(file, "update.apk");
                if(outputFile.exists()){
                    outputFile.delete();
                }
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                }
                fos.close();
                is.close();
                outputFile.setReadable(true, false);

                Log.i(TAG, "Completed download of update file");
                statusMessage = "Completed download of update file";

                Uri uri;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, getString(R.string.file_provider_authority), outputFile);
                } else {
                    uri = Uri.fromFile(outputFile);
                }

                Log.i(TAG, "URI successfully set");
                statusMessage = "URI successfully set";

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);

            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, ex.toString());
                thrown = ex;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
            status.setText("");
            if (statusMessage != null) {
                status.setText(statusMessage);
            }
            if (thrown != null) {
                status.setText(context.toString());
                message.setText(thrown.toString());
            }
            outputFile.delete();
            super.onPostExecute(v);
        }
    }
}
```

The `AndroidManifest.xml` file contains the following entry:

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="@strings/file_provider_authority"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

`file_provider_paths.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <cache-path name="cache" path="."/>
</paths>
```

I have tried changing `context` to both `getApplication()` and `getApplicationContext()` which both result in a `NullPointerException` but with slightly different resource wording.

What else can I try to resolve this problem?

**EDIT:**

I have modified the code to try and get to the bottom of the problem:

```
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                statusMessage = "Context is: " + context.getString(R.string.file_provider_authority);
                uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getString(R.string.file_provider_authority), outputFile);
                statusMessage = "uri set";
            } else {
                uri = Uri.fromFile(outputFile);
            }
```

`statusMessage` gets set to show the correct Provider Authority string.  It does not get set to "uri set".  Therefore it is definitely the `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` that is failing.

Given that `context` is not null and the Authority is the correct string, what else could be throwing the error here?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call getString inside an non activity class try to replace

```
getString(R.string.file_provider_authority)
```

with

```
context.getString(R.string.file_provider_authority)
```

edit: I see you are extending activity in your `Update` class did you declare it in the manifests? Why are you extending activity if you are already passing a context?

Comment: Good point about extending `Activity` and passing `context` - it came about because at some point a reference back to `MainActivity` was needed.  I've now removed `extends Activity` and used `context.getString(R.string.file_provider_authority)` which throws a different error:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.XmlParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager.java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: I've now added a check that confirms `context.getString(R.string.file_provider_authority)` is working so the issue is something else